# Play InputStream using MediaPlayer

Tags: android

I have an `InputStream` from bluetooth (using SPP) camera that I want to display on Android.
is there a way to feed this InputStream to MediaPlayer or any other control to display video.

Comment: I need this solution. I have Stream from Http.

Comment: sorry, but I did not find a solution yet